# how to set data from server in one field & hard coded data in another field of store in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

Hi I am developing a chart application in this data is coming from server for both xField and yField of series, but I wanted only yField`s( numeric value e.g. 10, 20, 30, 55, 88 for columns of chart ) data to come from server and make xField ( Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec ) data to hard coded in Store. so that application works faster
my application screen shot is attached [here.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73250761/chartApp.PNG) and code I have attached [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73250761/main.txt)

code file has Model, Store and View  code.If you see screen shot of application which I have attached, I have rounded with red color the xField`s label which I want to make hard coded. please guide me

Comment: How about just posting your `Model` and Store` code here? It would make things a lot easier.

Comment: @jakerella in above question i have already given link of my code.could you please see that.

Comment: could someone answer my question. please